# Is there an optimal algorithm for calculating net requirements of components?

Tags: java, algorithm

Say I have a list of items, such as 5 tables, 5 chairs, etc.
Each table is made up of 4 legs, and a tabletop.
Each leg is made up of 2 pieces of wood, a tabletop is made up of 5 piece of wood and 4 screws, etc.

I have the list of item components stored in a database with columns (item1, item2, amount), where item2 is a component of item1, and 'amount' being the number of item2s required.

I want to calculate the total net requirements for a list of lowest-level materials, with no assumptions about the number of hierarchy levels, is there an optimal way to do this?

If it matters, I am planning to do this in Java.

Comment: I don't know if this is optimal, but if the list fits the main memory, I'd keep a hashmap of a flatten relationship between each item and its most basic components quantities before starting the calculation.

Comment: That would be nice, but I actually need the data to be stored by only its components one level down. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

You've actually described your solution!

What you can do is create a tree. Several trees, actually, since you mention chairs and tables which would be separate trees.

The node should contain item1, and its children should be every one of its components, along with a count of how many of those it needs. So, you'd have a list of children, i.e. (Wood, 2) (Nail, 4)

As you create nodes, add them to a Map so you can easily keep track of whether the item has been made so you can use the same one. A Node with no parent should always be added to the List of Trees. A node with a parent should be removed from the List of Trees (Tree Roots are top-level components in this definition).

As you populate the tree, use the above information. No parent = new tree. Then check to see if it uses any trees to build its components. If it does, remove that Tree from the list of Trees.

So let's say we have Leg Chair Tabletop ChairTop Desk

We'd add Leg as a root. It has children wood and nails inside it, which we create.

Then we'd add Chair, which uses Leg, so we remove Leg from the List of Trees and add it to Chair, and add Chair to the List of Trees.

TableTop is made of wood, so we take the Wood node and add it as a child, but TableTop and Chair are unrelated so TableTop is now a new tree.

ChairTop is part of Chair, so we add it as a child to Chair and its parts, if not wood, are added as nodes.

Desk is made of TableTop so it becomes the root and TableTop is no longer the root of a tree.

End result is Desk and Chair as Trees; TableTop, ChairTop, Leg as nodes; Wood and whatever else as leaf nodes.

The lowest-level materials of all your trees are the basic components.

Once you're done with that, you can write a method that basically iterates through the children and passes back a list of items/counts that multiplies everything properly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a tree is the best structure to go with. Consider following diagram:

[image: chair making diagram]

Here chair is made from 2 wooden sticks and 4 wooden planks. You can also create support for making 4 wooden sticks from 1 raw wood by saying that 1 stick costs 0.25 raw wood.

However, this is *not* a tree. You could enforce it to be a tree, by making 2 `raw wood` nodes, but on bigger diagrams that would cause huge memory inefficiency.

What you do have, is an [Oriented graph with no oriented cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (oriented cycles would be *bad*, like you need hammer to make iron, but you need iron to make hammer).

Now, how to make efficient lookup of basic elements? Let's assume that the database will not be changed during the time the program runs, that will allow us some optimalizations. If you are looking for time efficiency, I would recommend each node having a `Map<String, Double>` map of raw materials needed to create this node's element. To initialize this map, just sum together all the maps of this node's children, multiplied by the coefficient of how much of that element you need to create this element. If the children's map is not initialized yet, initialize it recursively.

The question is how often too look into the database? For better convenience, I would keep an additional `Map<String, Node>` map from names to existing nodes, like if you see that chair needs wooden sticks, you can look if you have already used wooden sticks for something else and thus you don't need to recompute their raw materials. So you look in the database only the stuff you need and never the same thing twice.

Or for smaller database, you could initialize the whole graph at start, but you are risking that if some items will not be requested, you have wasted your time and memory.

**EDIT:**

The problem complicates if we wanted to allow the database to change, let's consider more nodes:

[image: graph with more nodes]

If the red line changed it's value (for example more efficient way to create pre-proccessed wood is found) then we need to invalidate all the orange nodes (by some `isValid` flag or something). We can do that easily if each node also remembers it's parents.

When materials for `chair` are requested, it needs to be re-validated, so it will ask `wooden stick`, that needs to be re-validated too and so on. But then, `chair` will ask `wooden plank` to get re-valuated, but that *will not* cause `processable wood` to be re-valuated again, since it is still valid from the time when `wooden stick` was being validated.

@Compass: and that is the behaviour you get, because this graph is *not* a tree. If it was tree, it would look like this:

[image: graph as forest]

(That is actually a [forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#forest) and we would have to omit the orientation first, but the idea is the same) Now imagine how difficult it would be to keep that thing updated.

Comment: Well, visually, it looks like that, but consider the nodes to be representing an arbitrary value. So it'd be a tree with c as the root, 2s and 4p as children, and s has a child 0.25w, and p has a child 0.5w Conceptually speaking, it's easier to keep track of the objects once, I think. The amount of a single object is stored in the object's parent, and as far as operations things go, parents of children are actually not tracked, so you can't go back up into another tree.

Comment: if `s` has `0.25w` as a child, and `p` has `0.5w` as a child, then the graph is not a tree, unless there are 2 different `w`s. On the other hand, you don't need the graph *at all* if you don't consider the database data changing and you can get by with just the map of existing nodes (more like lists of raw materials, than nodes). But if database would change, it would make a difference if the graph is a tree with duplicate nodes or not when updating.

Comment: I mean the "literal" value. A tree with root of 5 can have two children 3 and 2. Child 3 has 2 children 1 and 2. Child 2 has 2 children 1 and 1. Is it a pretty tree? Not really. Still a summation of parts. All we're doing in this case is presenting the object as part of the value. The node's "child" may be shared across multiple elements, but the represented "child" is the number times the component.

Comment: Then the "problem" may be that we have different definition of what is a tree. For me, tree is a [connected graph without cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory) "wiki"). The fact that each node has a list of children doesn't make it a tree.

Comment: For me, a tree is [something with branches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29). Storage-wise, the example may violate by the fact that we're reusing Objects of the same type, but externally, we can visualize it as a tree. As you've shown in your image, you're assigning values to your branches. Those values ostensibly are related to the leaf, so you could technically have two leafs labeled 0.25wood and 0.5wood and then that would be a valid tree.

Comment: Sry, didn't notice the fixed link until I edited the answer. In that sence, it might appear as a tree, but it still doesn't have a global root and one node can have multiple parents, so it is like a little modified tree.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> bom;
void componentLookup(String itemCode) {
  List<ComponentEntry> ces = findByItem1(itemCode);
  for (ComponentEntry ce : ces) {
    if (ce.item2 == null) {
      // component without child-components, update the BOM...
      if (bom.containsKey(ce.item1)) {
        bom.put(ce.item1, bom.get(ce.item1) + ce.amount);
      } else {
        bom.put(ce.item1, ce.amount);
      }
    } else {
      // component with child-components, proceed deeper lookup...
      componentLookup(ce.item2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is basically a [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) and yes, there are optimal algorithms to visit a tree. 
I believe this is a tree because you don't want to have circular dependencies, i.e. you don't want item1 to depend on item2 and, ad the same time, item2 to depend on item1 (and in general you don't want more complex cycles).

There are many algorithms you can use both for [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) and for [breadth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). You can pick the one that best fits your time and space needs (you find additional information about time and space in the provided links). You will also find Java code.